# Update database and refresh activity from another class when a card is clicked

Tags: android, api, android-recyclerview, android-volley, cardview

I want that when anyone click on the CardView with Status=undone there should run an API and the database is updated and the refreshed data is loaded in RecyclerView.

This is my UpdateStatus.class having the RecyclerView data:

```
TextView Cid,Tno,Tname,Cono,Work;
private static final String 
URL_GETDATA="";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_status);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String cid = bundle.getString("checkID");
    String tno = bundle.getString("trainno");
    String tname = bundle.getString("trainname");
    String cno = bundle.getString("coachno");
    String works = bundle.getString("work");

    Cid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.idValue);
    Cid.setText(cid);

    Tno=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tnoValue);
    Tno.setText(tno);

    Tname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tnameValue);
    Tname.setText(tname);

    Cono=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cnoValue);
    Cono.setText(cno);

    Work=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.workValue);
    Work.setText(works);

    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    listItems=new ArrayList<>();
    loadRecyclerViewData();
}

private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
    final AlertDialog dialog=new SpotsDialog(this, "Loading Data ...");
    dialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_GETDATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.v("Response",response);
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            ListItem item;
                            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("done")){
                                item=new ListItem(
                                        jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("checkID"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("plannedDate"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("actualDate"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("status"),
                                        R.drawable.done
                                );
                            }else {
                                item=new ListItem(
                                        jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("checkID"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("plannedDate"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("actualDate"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("status"),
                                        R.drawable.update
                                );
                            }

                            listItems.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter=new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            // Posting params to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("checkID",bundle.getString("checkID"));
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

This is my Adapter.class where the CardView data is loaded onClick on Card the Status is checked and An API will run using Volley and UpdateStatus activity must be refreshed with new data:

```
private List<ListItem> listItems;
private Context context;
private static final String 

public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ListItem listItem=listItems.get(position);

    holder.planned.setText(listItem.getPlanned());
    holder.actual.setText(listItem.getActual());
    holder.status.setImageResource(listItem.getmImageResourceid());
    Intent i=new Intent(context,UpdateStatus.class);
    holder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                if(listItem.getStatus().equals("undone")){
                    //update code here
                }
                Toast.makeText(context,"You Clicked "+listItem.getStatus(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView planned,actual;
    public ImageView status;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        planned=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.planned_date);
        actual=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.actual_date);
        status=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OnResponse from volley when you adding a new data to your recyclerView just called a method `recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`

see the changes in you code below-:

```
 @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.v("Response",response);
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        ListItem item;
                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("done")){
                            item=new ListItem(
                                    jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("checkID"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("plannedDate"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("actualDate"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("status"),
                                    R.drawable.done
                            );
                        }else {
                            item=new ListItem(
                                    jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("checkID"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("plannedDate"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("actualDate"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("status"),
                                    R.drawable.update
                            );
                        }

                        listItems.add(item);
                    }
                    adapter=new MyAdapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged()

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },
```

Or for better user experience you can use `recyclerView.notifyItemInserted(int position)` instead of `recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged()`. see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)